# Script Code to check for File exist in FTP

Tags: unix

Can someone help me to write the Unxi Script to check for the file ABC.txt in FTP location and give result as "Ok" or "No File" . The result "Ok" or "No File" should be written in File XYZ.

Regards,
Sriram

Comment: What if the FTP login fails?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right :

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -l ABC.txt  > temp.txt

wc -l temp.txt > temp2.txt

some_var=$(sed 's/[^0-9]//g' temp2.txt)

if [ $some_var -eq 1 ]
then
      echo "Ok"
else
      echo "No file"
fi

rm -f temp.txt
rm -f temp2.txt
```

That's the script that answers the question "Is ABC.txt present in the directory?"

But you need to login in order to use this so : Follow the routine described in here http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html in order to be able to SSH to given host without requiring a password and then add the following line at the top of the above script "ssh user@host".

Hope that helps..

P.S Using ssh is way easier and i think it's better than using ftp :)